# bootstrap 4 Dropdown does not work locally

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, navbar, local, dropdown

Good day, I have an issue, I have a simple code and I want to run it locally so I create manually the popper.js and jquery (by copying the code in a file and save it as .js) but dropdown that is inside of the navbar does not work, even if I put only the dropdown alone still the problem so here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Pruebas</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon_16.ico"/>
    <link rel="bookmark" href="favicon_16.ico"/>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="dist/js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, are you sure all the files with the exact name are there in js folder? Plus also could you check console for any errors?

Comment: Yes, all names are correct, that is my problem, I've checked the files, folder's names

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: Nope, no errors

Comment: can you make an example or send the folder to look into